# vim+LaTeX Suite: How to jump to the Error List window?

Tags: vim

I am trying to learn how to use vim latex-suite and following the tutorial, [A (very) quick introduction to Latex-Suite](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite-quickstart/index.html). When I compiled and got some errors, I see the Error List, etc with split windows.

I am in [Debugging LaTeX source files](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite-quickstart/lsq-debugging.html) page of the tutorial. It says "Jump to the Error List window and try scrolling around...", but how can I jump to the Error List?

Comment: Which tutorial are you referring to?

Comment: @tehingo Added a link for the tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ctrl-W w,

Ctrl-W starts a (W)indow jumping. Some plugin (minibuffer) lets you do Ctrl-W j (j as down), google around to see how it is achieved.

Or, if you have a terminal that's properly configured, or you are using gvim, just use mouse to click the Error List window. Actually for this installation when I tried \ll, the cursor automatically jumped down into the Error List window.

Answer (score 1):

You can also issue the **:copen** command which will open/focus the error list (depending on whether or not the list is already visible).