# How do you jump to an error from the Error List in LaTeX-suite?

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I just discovered LaTeX-suite and was overjoyed with the breadth of the compiling and debugging options, but for some reason the primary debugging mechanism is not working for me.

When I compile with `\ll` I get the expected log output, and then the "Quickfix List" window appears and gains focus. The reference manual appears to indicate that simply pressing enter should move focus to the source window at the location of the error, but for me it does nothing but minimize the accompanying log output preview.

The reference at http://folk.uio.no/haaksk/config-files/.vim/doc/latex-suite.html indicates

```
You can then scroll through the errors and press <enter> to be taken to the location
of the corresponding error´unless you set the g:Tex_GotoError variable to 0.
```

Even with `Tex_GotoError` set to `1` I do not get the expected behaviour, and I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: try auctex and emacs ;)

Comment: Which version of vim & latex-suite are you using? What is in your vimrc?

Comment: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 with vim-latexsuite 20130126-1 (sorry, this is the only "versioning" I can seem to find)

Comment: Woops, missed the edit window; my vimrc is at http://pastebin.com/ZJQ5rnVH ; and as for emacs I'm not looking for new OS, just a new text editor plugin.

Comment: try Ctrl-Ww. I found it here: [vim+LaTeX Suite: How to jump to the Error List window?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32369/vimlatex-suite-how-to-jump-to-the-error-list-window)

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Did you fixed it?

Comment: I am also having the same issue. It is not a matter of the cursor being in the wrong window. When the cursor is over the error in the quickfix window, pressing enter only minimizes the log output preview.

Answer (score 6):

I just tested this out and it appears the problem you are having is that after compilation the cursor is left in the document and not in the error list. Moving between windows can be done simply with `CTRL-W CTRL-W` (this moves to the 'next' window - there are more window switching keystrokes - look them up with `:help CTRL-W`).

Once in the error window hitting `CR` (return) will move you to the error. You can also use `:cnext` and `:cprev` to move back and forth in the error list. Use `:cfirst` and `:clast` to move to the first and last error respectively.

(Note: this 'error list' is in fact a VIM quickfix list - info on that can be found using `:help quickfix`).